# Django - Model structure suggestions for two classes referring to each other with ForeignKeys

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I've been trying to come up with a solution for what I'm trying to achieve. As part of  teaching myself django, I'm trying to create a club membership site for my martial arts club. As part of one of the apps I proposed two classes of model; Members and Schools.

The idea was to have the Members refer to which school they belong to with a ForeignKey, and for the schools to refer to the Members to identify the instructors. The instructors are just a normal Member with a BooleanField identifying if they're an instructor or not.

I just keep coming up against problem after problem, which I'm kinda solving one after another, but I wonder if what I'm doing in the first place is the most efficient way of doing it.

Here's what that part of the Members model looks like at present:

```
instructor = models.BooleanField('Instructor?', default=False)
school = models.ForeignKey('School')
```

and here's what the school class looks like:

```
class School(models.Model):
SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
    ('RED', 'Redruth - Centre of Excellence'),
    ('FAL', 'Falmouth - FXU'),
    ('MEV', 'Mevagissey'),
    )

name = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=SCHOOL_CHOICES, default='RED')
instructors = models.ForeignKey('Student', related_name='instructors', blank=True, null=True)
```

I had to add the related_name to the instructors ForeignKey, as without it it threw errors. I also tried adding a to_field to the school ForeignKey in the Members model as at present it's just showing three copies of 'school object' at the moment, but that didn't seem to change it (edit: fixed that with **unicode** definition).

Is the way I'm doing it (two classes referring to one another with ForeignKeys) the best way of doing it, or should I be doing something else?

Sorry for being so vague :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're marking the instructors on the `Member` model, you don't need to identify them with another relation on the `School` model.  Instead, if you want to get the instructors, for a particular school you can just do:

```
instructors = Members.objects.filter(instructor=True, school=my_school)
```

Comment: See, I knew there'd be something far simpler and more elegant I was overlooking, thank you.

Comment: @TSDAdam On a somewhat related note, you might be able to get rid of the `School` model altogether--if the `name` is the only field on the model, and there are only 3 static choices, there's no need to commit that to the database.  Just make the `school` field on `Member` be a `CharField` with `choices` (exactly like `School.name` is now).  If your model is more complex than that, you should probably still remove the choices unless you anticipate having several `School` instances with the same name that you need to regularize.

Comment: Annoyingly that's exactly how I had it before, school was just a choice within the Member model. I hadn't even considered using the filter to be able to display and sort instructors and schools, hence me trying to give it its own model and tying the two together.